# How do I get the value of a UITextfield as characters are being typed in real time?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, alert

I am attempting to regulate the input of a UITextfield in real time, meaning as a user is typing. I have this character set that i need to compare to the input string, and while editing if an unwarranted character is typed in, I want to relay an alert. Here is my character set :

`let acceptedChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_")`

now how do i capture a specific textfield in real time and track its input?

Comment: You can use the UITextField Delegate method textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: for this purpose

Comment: Set a delegate to your text field, and handle the check in 'textFieldShouldEndEditing' method- Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldEndEditing:

Comment: my original code is called within `textFieldShouldEndEditing` it doesn't track input in real time @nshebbar

Comment: can you elaborate on how i can check the string for characters not in that set using that method @Nandu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let invalidCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_").invertedSet
        if let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(invalidCharacters, options: nil, range:Range<String.Index>(start: string.startIndex, end: string.endIndex)) {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: where in that method do i specify the textfield i want to target?

Comment: Check if(textfield == yourTextfield){}

Answer (score 3):

You can register  your textField for value change event like this

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action:"textFieldDidChange", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(){
    // put your code
}
```

It will work for each chracter you have been typed in real time

Comment: Perfect and simple! Works for me.Great job!

Answer (score 1):

```
var strings: NSString?
```

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate //set your textfield delegate

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{  if(textField .isEqual(your textfield))
    {
    strings=string;
    let acceptedChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_").invertedSet;

     if (strings!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(acceptedChars.invertedSet).location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }        
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: i tagged swift not obj c

Comment: can you provide a swift answer

Comment: no it literally just updated on my screen @UsamaSadiq

Comment: the textfield delegate is already set, my question is where in that method do i set the specific textfield i want to target

Comment: did you create outlet for that textfield

Comment: if(textField .isEqual(your textfield))
        {}

Answer (score 0):

## use below method

```
   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        if textField.isEqual(<textField whose value to be copied>)
        {
            <TextField to be updated>.text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        }
    
        return true
    }
```

Comment: where in that method do i add my custom character set?

Answer (score 0):

An Easy Delegate method and really more efficient is:

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print(textField.text)
}
```